# How do join two lists without have same fields using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

```
Class sam
{
    public void m1()
    {
        List<int> A = new List<int>() {1,2,3};
        List<int> B = new List<int>() {4,5,6};

        for (int i = 0; i < A.count; i++)
        {
            c.add(m2(A[i], B[i]));
        }
    }

    public int M2(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

In this program i retrive from two lists and pass aruguments. I like call the method m2 in linQ

Answer (score 4):

It's unclear from the question, but perhaps you mean:

```
var C = A.Zip(B, (a, b) => a + b)
         .ToList();
```

If you want to hand over the addition to your `M2` method, you could do:

```
// C# 4
var C = A.Zip(B, M2); 

// C# 3 (not likely since Zip was introduced in .NET 4)
var C = A.Zip(B, (a, b) => M2(a, b)); 
var C = A.Zip<int, int, int>(B, M2);
```

Comment: I like achieve it by method call only not directly

Comment: @ratty: That isn't clear at all. Perhaps you could give us some sample input / output? Or something that compiles.

Comment: @ratty: Then replace the lambda with the method: `A.Zip(B, M2)`

Comment: @VVS: I think you might be onto something. I've put that in.

Comment: @Ani: I don't understand why there's a different C# 3 version.

Comment: @VVS: C# 3.0 Return Type Inference Does Not Work On Method Groups http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/05/c-3-0-return-type-inference-does-not-work-on-member-groups.aspx

Comment: @Ani: Hmm, wasn't aware of that limitation. Thanks.